# How to use AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter for multiple tracks (audio and video) simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, transcoding, avassetwriter

I know how to use `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetWriter`, and have successfully used them to grab a video track from one movie and transcode it into another. However, I'd like to do this with audio as well. Do I have to create and `AVAssetExportSession` after I've done with the initial transcode, or is there some way to switch between tracks while in the midst of a writing session? I'd hate to have to deal with the overhead of an `AVAssetExportSession`.

I ask because, using the pull style method - `while ([assetWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {...}` - assumes one track only. How could it be used for more than one track, i.e. both an audio and a video track?

Comment: Would you be able to point me in the right direction to learn how to transcode using AVAssetWriter?  Just looking to transcode to lower bitrate and resolution?

Answer (score 8):

`AVAssetWriter` will automatically interleave requests on its associated `AVAssetWriterInput`s in order to integrate different tracks into the output file. Just add an `AVAssetWriterInput` for each of the tracks that you have, and then call `requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:usingBlock:` on each of your `AVAssetWriterInput`s.

Here's a method I have that calls `requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:usingBlock:`. I call this method from a loop over the number of output/input pairs I have. (A separate method is good both for code readability and also because, unlike a loop, each call sets up a separate stack frame for the block.)

You only need one `dispatch_queue_t` and can reuse it for all of the tracks. Note that you definitely should *not* call `dispatch_async` from your block, because `requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:usingBlock:` expects the block to, well, block until it has filled in as much data as the `AVAssetWriterInput` will take. You don't want to return before then.

```
- (void)requestMediaDataForTrack:(int)i {
  AVAssetReaderOutput *output = [[_reader outputs] objectAtIndex:i];
  AVAssetWriterInput *input = [[_writer inputs] objectAtIndex:i];

  [input requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:_processingQueue usingBlock:
    ^{
      [self retain];
      while ([input isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer;
        if ([_reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading &&
            (sampleBuffer = [output copyNextSampleBuffer])) {

          BOOL result = [input appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
          CFRelease(sampleBuffer);

          if (!result) {
            [_reader cancelReading];
            break;
          }
        } else {
          [input markAsFinished];

          switch ([_reader status]) {
            case AVAssetReaderStatusReading:
              // the reader has more for other tracks, even if this one is done
              break;

            case AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted:
              // your method for when the conversion is done
              // should call finishWriting on the writer
              [self readingCompleted];
              break;

            case AVAssetReaderStatusCancelled:
              [_writer cancelWriting];
              [_delegate converterDidCancel:self];
              break;

            case AVAssetReaderStatusFailed:
              [_writer cancelWriting];
              break;
          }

          break;
        }
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: Whats with the `[self retain]`? Won't that just keep incrementing the retain count on the object an arbitrary amount? Who is releasing this object?

Comment: The intention may have been for `readingCompleted` to release the object. That being said, it may be unnecessary as the presence of the `[self readingCompleted]` call should cause the runtime to retain `self` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using two AVAssetWriterInputs and pushing the samples through a worker queue? Here is a rough sketch.

```
processing_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mydomain.gcdqueue.mediaprocessor", NULL);

[videoAVAssetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:myInputSerialQueue usingBlock:^{
    dispatch_asyc(processing_queue, ^{process video});
}];

[audioAVAssetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:myInputSerialQueue usingBlock:^{
    dispatch_asyc(processing_queue, ^{process audio});
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it, but couldn't figure out how to properly end the writing session. With one track, I just see if copyNextSampleBuffer returns empty, then end the session. With multiple tracks, I tried creating a flag for when the audio or video was done, and if both were complete I would end the session. However, even though I did a check for the asset reader status being AVAssetReaderStatusReading, I kept getting the error: [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer] cannot copy next sample buffer unless the asset reader is in the 'reading' state'

Comment: I will bet testing a strategy much like this in the near future. If I find a solution I will post back.

Comment: Are you calling [AVAssetWriterInput markAsFinished]; in your requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue method? I would not call that method at all, but rather call finishWriting on the AVAssetWriter when everything is complete.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I wasn't notified of the comment. I only call finishWriting, just as you're doing.

Comment: By the way, your "'reading' state" error may actually be a codec issue. If the inputs and outputs are not compatible formats that's the way it will sometimes surface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatch groups!

Check out the AVReaderWriter example for MacOSX...

I am quoting directly from the sample RWDocument.m:

```
- (BOOL)startReadingAndWritingReturningError:(NSError **)outError
{
    BOOL success = YES;
    NSError *localError = nil;

    // Instruct the asset reader and asset writer to get ready to do work
    success = [assetReader startReading];
    if (!success)
        localError = [assetReader error];
    if (success)
    {
        success = [assetWriter startWriting];
        if (!success)
            localError = [assetWriter error];
    }

    if (success)
    {
        dispatch_group_t dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();

        // Start a sample-writing session
        [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:[self timeRange].start];

        // Start reading and writing samples
        if (audioSampleBufferChannel)
        {
            // Only set audio delegate for audio-only assets, else let the video channel drive progress
            id <RWSampleBufferChannelDelegate> delegate = nil;
            if (!videoSampleBufferChannel)
                delegate = self;

            dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup);
            [audioSampleBufferChannel startWithDelegate:delegate completionHandler:^{
                dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup);
            }];
        }
        if (videoSampleBufferChannel)
        {
            dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup);
            [videoSampleBufferChannel startWithDelegate:self completionHandler:^{
                dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup);
            }];
        }

        // Set up a callback for when the sample writing is finished
        dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, serializationQueue, ^{
            BOOL finalSuccess = YES;
            NSError *finalError = nil;

            if (cancelled)
            {
                [assetReader cancelReading];
                [assetWriter cancelWriting];
            }
            else
            {
                if ([assetReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusFailed)
                {
                    finalSuccess = NO;
                    finalError = [assetReader error];
                }

                if (finalSuccess)
                {
                    finalSuccess = [assetWriter finishWriting];
                    if (!finalSuccess)
                        finalError = [assetWriter error];
                }
            }

            [self readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:finalSuccess withError:finalError];
        });

        dispatch_release(dispatchGroup);
    }

    if (outError)
        *outError = localError;

    return success;
}
```

Comment: Notice the dispatch group notify command at the end to know when all audio/video is finished... this is offscreen rendering... not realtime

Comment: "Offscreen" and "real-time" are not opposites; "rendered" and "off-screen" are (and do). "Real-time" is subjective to an observer, and describes the display rate of video frames as they are acquired from their source. It has no opposite, not even "non-real-time." You wouldn't want a transcoder to work at a real-time pace. Transcoding should happen as quickly as possible; there are dedicated devices for this in the broadcast industry. Nothing goes slower than normal real-time, anyway. Even playback software has to pace video to keep it from displaying faster than it can be perceived.