# UIImagePickerController 720p video for iphone 4s/5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController to record videos and I always want the output video to be 1280 x 720 (small enough for other purposes), but in iphone 4s/iphone 5, the output video will be 1920 x 1280. I cannot find a proper configuration that helps me to make the video exactly 1280 x 720.

```
   UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh            = 0,
   UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium          = 1,  // default value
   UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow             = 2,
   UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480         = 3,
```

High will be 1920 x 1280 in iPhone 4s/iPhone 5

Comment: For iOS above 5.0 you can use any of followings:

UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720 = 4
UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540 = 5



But video size on disk is in MBs. Trying to find out a solution for that also.

Comment: Were you able to find the way to get video exactly of size 1280x720 ? Can you please share your experience/insight help ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this thread could help! 
You should use google before asking questions like this. :D

[Link to thread on stackoverf.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751883/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-video-created-with-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: that link doesn't work for my purpose, I want to configure the UIImagePickerController not to put the video into another process