# Video Compression when Recording Movie with UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iphone app,if I select a video using `UIImagePicker`-it is automatically compressed

Is there any way to compress the video after recording ?
I am posting my recorded video to server, will the quality equal to non compressed video ?

Comment: There is, I've answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16035330/884119

Answer (score -1):

Use custom class(SDAVAssetExportSession
) to do the video compression. You can download it from this link. After downloading add SDAVAssetExportSession.h and SDAVAssetExportSession.m files into your project, Then the below code will help to do the compression

```
- (void)compressVideoWithInputVideoUrl:(NSURL *) inputVideoUrl
{
    /* Create Output File Url */

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *finalVideoURLString = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"compressedVideo.mp4"];
    NSURL *outputVideoUrl = ([[NSURL URLWithString:finalVideoURLString] isFileURL] == 1)?([NSURL URLWithString:finalVideoURLString]):([NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalVideoURLString]); // Url Should be a file Url, so here we check and convert it into a file Url


    SDAVAssetExportSession *compressionEncoder = [SDAVAssetExportSession.alloc initWithAsset:[AVAsset assetWithURL:inputVideoUrl]]; // provide inputVideo Url Here
    compressionEncoder.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    compressionEncoder.outputURL = outputVideoUrl; //Provide output video Url here
    compressionEncoder.videoSettings = @
    {
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: @800,   //Set your resolution width here
    AVVideoHeightKey: @600,  //set your resolution height here
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: @
        {
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @45000, // Give your bitrate here for lower size give low values
        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264High40,
        },
    };
    compressionEncoder.audioSettings = @
    {
    AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @2,
    AVSampleRateKey: @44100,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey: @128000,
    };

    [compressionEncoder exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         if (compressionEncoder.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
         {
            NSLog(@"Compression Export Completed Successfully");
         }
         else if (compressionEncoder.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Compression Export Canceled");
         }
         else
         {
              NSLog(@"Compression Failed");

         }
     }];

}

To Cancel Compression Use Below Line Of code
 [compressionEncoder cancelExport]; //Video compression cancel
```