# Phonegap video capture reduce output file size

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, cordova, capture

When capturing video with phonegap on iOS the file size for a even a 1min capture is ridiculously large. Well, far to large to upload over a 3G connection reliably. I read that there is a native AVCaptureSession object that will allow the bitrate to be altered in order to reduce the file size. Has anyone implemented this in the phonegap video capture or can give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Found the deatils I needed here:

[How can I reduce the file size of a video created with UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751883/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-video-created-with-uiimagepickercontroller)

The important line for Phonegap users is in CDVCapture.m:

pickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;

There are several presets that can be used e.g.

UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow

Answer (score 0):

phonegap provide quality argument when to navigate camera set :

```
quality:50
```

this is recommended for ios. if u need to reduce mean reduce quality.It have integer value (0-100) use this .....