# where to save output of AVAssetWriter - iOS

Tags: ios, compression, avfoundation, video-capture, avassetwriter

I'm following some examples of how to compress a video to reduce file size prior to uploading it to a server. Specifically, I've looked at this question here: [How can I reduce the file size of a video created with UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751883/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-video-created-with-uiimagepickercontroller/16035330#16035330)

However, I'm wondering where the best place to save the output is.

Even the AV foundation programming guide only provides this as an example:

```
NSError *outError;
NSURL *outputURL = <#NSURL object representing the URL where you want to save the   video#>;
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:outputURL
                                                  fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                     error:&outError];
BOOL success = (assetWriter != nil);
```

Again, looking for some guidance on exactly where it is I want to save the video!

Cheers,
Brendan

Answer (score 0):

This is documents directory URL, just append your filename:

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Almost the same for all others: library (`NSLibraryDirectory`)

Answer (score 0):

You can write file in document directory using below code

defile document directory path

```
NSString *DocumentsDirectoryPath() {NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];return documentsDirectoryPath;}
```

and then

```
NSURL * outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[DocumentsDirectoryPath() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfilename.mp4"]];
```

here `mp4` is your file extention.