# Record videos on iOS device at a specific bitrate

Tags: ios, video, transcoding

I want to create an app which records video and saves it to the local device, but it needs to record at a specific bitrate. Currently when a video is recorded on an iOS device, it has to be downloaded and transcoded into a streamable size. Rather than having to download and transcode (which takes time) it would be far better if the device just recorded with a maximum bitrate in mind.

Is that possible?

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751883/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-video-created-with-uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality of what you record is UIImagePickerController is based on the enumeration `UIImagePickerControllerQualityType` those settings can change in different devices.
If you use `AVFoundation`, with `AVCaptureSession` you have a similar property called [`-sessionPreset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureSession/sessionPreset) some of these are fixed others due to devices hardware.
But you have also the freedom to select the best framerate by using the [`-activeFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/activeFormat) property on an `AVCaptureDevice`.
There is no way to change the bitrate in realtime, but you can export the movie you recorded using `AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput`. More info [here](http://finalize.com/2014/10/21/exporting-a-video-in-ios-to-reduce-size-and-ensure-maximum-client-compatibility/).