# iOS - video compressing with maintaining quality like WhatsApp but size reduced using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using UIImagePickerController and I want to reduce the file size of the video imported but quality still good:

I am using the following code:

```
func addAttachmentUtil(from : String)
    {
        let file = UIImagePickerController()
        file.delegate = self
        file.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        file.videoMaximumDuration = 600

        file.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
        file.videoQuality = .type640x480

        file.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(file, animated: true)
        {
        }
    }
```

The code above compresses the video and the video loses its quality. How do I compress the video same like WhatsApp does and still maintain the quality?

I went through this answer at: [iPhone:Programmatically compressing recorded video to share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687341/iphoneprogrammatically-compressing-recorded-video-to-share/5853354#5853354) but it is for Objective C and I am unable to figure out a Swift version for this. It will very helpful if someone could help me with a Swift version for this.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470637/swift-compressing-video-files)

Comment: @jagdeepsingh, can you help me find module for this  : Use of undeclared type 'AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate'