# Reduce video bitrate swift

Tags: ios, swift, video-processing, video-compression

Im using uiimagepicker for the user to pick a video from photo library.

After setting video quality to low in image picker settings, a 5 minute or even a 2 min recorded video is still too big for upload. Is there anyway to compress the video size further. My guess is that i need to reduce the bitrate.

I am of course using assets to manage the file

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470637/swift-compressing-video-files or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751883/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-video-created-with-uiimagepickercontroller?rq=1

Comment: those answers above show you how to modify some of these settings that overall contribute to the file size and quality of the video. You may need to play around with them to find the right balance for you and your project. Obviosuly the higher the quality, resolution and other factors, the higher the file size