# Playing and Storing Videos From/To Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, avfoundation, firebase-storage

I have a video chat messaging app using `AVFoundation` and `Firebase` to record, store, and playback 1 minute-length videos.

Everything works accordingly, but there is a...

1. Delay in playing a fetched video
2. Delay in uploading a recorded video, especially long here

Ideally...

1. It'd be nice to "pre-load" a fetched video to play immediately on command, but it doesn't seem possible with `AVPlayer` where the loading and play happen only when the method `.play()` is invoked.
2. Would simultaneously uploading while the actual recording is taking place be something that's even possible? Or, does `Firebase Storage` work where once the network call to upload the video is first triggered, the app can enter the background and still complete?

I am admittedly a complete beginner in managing videos and I haven't found any concrete guides on how to eliminate or optimize the reduction of the delay for a better UX (i.e. Instagram playing and uploading an Instagram video story). Any help would be appreciated..

```
func playVideo(with outputFileURL: URL) {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.setView(view: self.progressBar, hidden: true)
        self.progressBar.progress = 0
        
        let asset = AVAsset(url: outputFileURL)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        self.avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
        
        let previewLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.avPlayer)
        previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)            
        
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()            
        
        self.avPlayer.play()
    }
}

func uploadVideo(_ url: URL) {
    
    let filename = "x"
    
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("videos").child("xyz").child(filename)
            
    let uploadTask = ref.putFile(from: url, metadata: nil, completion: { (_, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to upload movie:", err)
            return
        }
        
        ref.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadUrl, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to get download url:", err)
                return
            }
            
            guard let downloadUrl = downloadUrl else { return }
            
            if let thumbnailImage = self.thumbnailImageForFileUrl(url) {
                
                self.uploadToFirebaseStorageUsingImage(thumbnailImage, completion: { (imageUrl) in                        
                    print("saved video url: \(downloadUrl) and saved image url: \(imageUrl)")
                })
            }

        })
    })

    uploadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in
        print("In Progress")
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.success) { (snapshot) in
        print("Done")
    }
}

func thumbnailImageForFileUrl(_ fileUrl: URL) -> UIImage? {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    
    do {
    
        let thumbnailCGImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 2, timescale: 60), actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailCGImage)
        
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Regarding your first question, look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, I looked into [compressing the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40470706/9466631).

The upload is **much** faster, but the quality is worse, which ideally should not have to be compromised.

If anyone has a better solution, would really appreciate and love to hear it!