# iOS: How to compress video to expected size if too big?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, compression

I would like to compress videos to an expected size if too big. For example, if my video is bigger than 2mb, I want to compress it next to 2mb. My goal is not to have a video superior to 2mb.

```
- (void)convertVideoToLowQualityWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL 
                                   outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL 
                                     handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) 
    {
        handler(exportSession);
        [exportSession release];
    }];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/josh/Desktop/output.mov"];
    [self convertVideoToLowQualityWithInputURL:videoURL outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)
     {
         if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
         {
             printf("completed\n");
         }
         else
         {
             printf("error\n");
         }
     }];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did it by follow instruction of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751883/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-video-created-with-uiimagepickercontroller My video was 20 MB and compress size was 1.6 MB

Comment: @iPatel Hi, I don't understand where you put the size to get a 2mb video for videos > to 2mb?