# How to compress video after getting result from PHPickerViewController xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode, video, compression, phpickerviewcontroller

I know that UIImagePickerController allows you to compress media content upon selection. However, I'm not sure how to do the same with PHPickerViewController. How can I compress a video after getting a result (`didFinishPicking`), (so I can reduce the amount of time to upload and download the data from then on)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `PHPickerViewController` does that, but there are other ways to do it depending on how you work with the picker:

1. If you're using the default picker configuration (i.e. creating a `PHPickerConfiguration` without passing the photo library and therefore not having the need to request permissions), you'll have to work with `NSItemProvider`. From what I learned, the only option might be to save the video to a temporary file using the item provider and the convert it to a lower resolution/bitrate using `AVAssetExportSession` (see some examples here: [How can I reduce the file size of a video created with UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11751883/426320)).
2. If you are using the picker with an explicitly passed photo library, the `PHPickerResult` will have the `assetIdentifier` provided to you, and you can use it to get a respective `PHAsset`. Then, use `PHImageManager`'s `requestAVAsset` method to get a video asset of a desired quality. You'll still need to export the `AVAsset` via `AVAssetExportSession` though, but with this approach you won't have a (potentially large) full-res temporary file on disk. I was recently working on a open source app that uses this technique, you can find some examples here: https://github.com/vadimbelyaev/TbilisiCleanups/blob/main/TbilisiCleanups/Services/MediaUploadService.swift

Comment: Thank you for this advice! My only worries are that it'll take longer to download and re-download the compress version, then upload to database, it seems like quite a process.